# No debug:scheduler in symfony console

Tags: symfony, symfony-scheduler

I tried to use the scheduler library. My Symfony version is 6.3.*.

I want to declare the following scheduler:
Something seems to go wrong, and my scheduler is not declared. Also, the debug:scheduler does not seem to exist.

```
<?php

namespace App\Scheduler;

use App\Message\MiseAJourEtatMessage;
use Symfony\Component\Scheduler\Attribute\AsSchedule;
use Symfony\Component\Scheduler\RecurringMessage;
use Symfony\Component\Scheduler\Schedule;
use Symfony\Component\Scheduler\ScheduleProviderInterface;

#[AsSchedule(name: 'default')]
class MainSchedule implements ScheduleProviderInterface {
    
    public function getSchedule(): Schedule {

        $schedule = new Schedule();

        return $schedule->add(RecurringMessage::every('4s', new MiseAJourEtatMessage()));
    }
}
```

Something seems to go wrong, as the command:
`php bin/console messenger:consume scheduler_default`

as the following result:
`The receiver "scheduler_start" does not exist.`

I made sure the following commands were run without errors:

`composer require symfony/scheduler symfony/messenger`

My composer.json is correctly updated with: `"symfony/scheduler": "6.4.*"`.

The folder vendor/symfony/scheduler is created, and I can find the declaration of the debug:scheduler method in Command/DebugCommand.php

`#[AsCommand(name: 'debug:scheduler', description: 'List schedules and their recurring messages')] final class` DebugCommand `extends Command {`

I tried to run:
`symfony console debug:scheduler`

The following message is printed in the console:
`Command "debug:scheduler" is not defined.`

Comment: Something is broken in your installation, but it's difficult to guess what. With the described commands, I do not get an error. Reinstall the packages, in case the installation is corrupted somehow.

Comment: Thanks ! You were right, my installation was broken. We did migrate the project, but some packages weren't correctly upgraded.
I created another project and imported the scheduler package, then i compared the two composer.json. I was able to see the packages at fault.

Comment: check my post: https://medium.com/@fico7489/symfony-scheduler-how-it-really-works-ef5d95409c09

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok so i solved it.
It was in fact errors in the packages i listed in my composer.json.
I created another project and imported the scheduler package, then compared the two composer.json. I was able to see the packages at fault.

Also, the '4s' in my calling of the method "every()" isn't correct and will generate an error when using 'symfony console debug:scheduler'.

I simply replaced it by the correct format : '4 seconds'.